# A Usage Application already exists in this farm - PowerShell error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

To enable develop dashboard we need to create the Usage and Health Data Collection Service Application.
For that I use the below powershell command to create the service application.

```
New-SPUsageApplication -Name "Health and Usage Application" -DatabaseName "SP2013_Health_and_Logging_Database".
```

Immediately after enter the command powershell shows an error says

> "New-SPUsageApplication : A Usage Application already exists in this
>   farm."

Comment: Did you let SharePoint create all the services when you installed the farm? Or did you do it manually? If you let SharePoint do it, you already have a Health and Usage Service. Go to central admin > application management > manage service application and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
$content = ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService)
$appsetting =$content.DeveloperDashboardSettings
$appsetting.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::On
$appsetting.Update()
```